# Entity not being loaded, or Mysterious "No property 'saveAll' found..." or "Could not safely identify store assignment..."

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I want JPA to recognize an entity, and generate the SQL necessary to create the table. I can get it to fail in one of the following ways. Below I show the error, followed by the code for the entity. The behavior changed depending on which package was used for things like Table so I deliberately showed which one was being used below.

Error: RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.woodsman.jpatutorial.orders.repositories.OrderHeaderRepository; If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
OrderHeader.java:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@Entity This should be simple, but I think there's several pack
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor This should be simple, but I think there's several pack
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Table(name = "order_header")
public class OrderHeader {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;      -->

    private String customerName;
}
```

Error: Error creating bean with name 'orderHeaderRepository' defined in com.woodsman.jpatutorial.orders.repositories.OrderHeaderRepository defined in @EnableJdbcRepositories declared on JdbcRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJdbcRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository.saveAllAndFlush(java.lang.Iterable); Reason: No property 'saveAll' found for type 'OrderHeader'
OrderHeaderRepository.java:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.woodsman.jpatutorial.orders.entities.OrderHeader;

@Repository
public interface OrderHeaderRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderHeader,Long>{

}
```

OrderHeader.java

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@Entity
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table(name = "order_header",schema = "orders")
public class OrderHeader {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;
    private String customerName;
}
```

application-h2.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:ordersdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MYSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=ordersadmin
spring.datasource.password=secret
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
database, ALWAYS initialize the database
spring.sql.init.mode=ALWAYS
spring.flyway.user=ordersadmin
spring.flyway.password=secret
spring.flyway.locations=db/migration,db/specific/h2
spring.flyway.defaultSchema=orders
```

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.data.jdbc.reposi     -->
tories.enabled=true
```

Update: Switched back to Spring Boot 2.7.3 and things work. Using Spring Boot version 3.0.0+ apparently removes the EnableJpaRepositories annotation. Without that annotation, and with the 3.0.0+ Spring Boot version, Spring said the entity wasn't a managed type. Per @M.Deinum's comment, I commented out spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc and the code did run, but it wouldn't actually generate the create sql.

I'm convinced that this *should* work in the 3.0.0-M5 Spring Boot, albeit with somewhat substantial changes to dependencies, and perhaps new annotations being added, so I'm not considering my question answered. Also, I made the entity id type Long to be consistent with the repository.

Comment: You are using the wrong `@Table` annotation. Which also means you have `spring-data-jdbc` or probably `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` as your dependency. Remove it. You want JPA *not* JDBC those are different things.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your thoughtful reply. I removed g:org.springframework.boot,a:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc. I didn't have spring-data-jdbc though. If I remove a:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, I loose JpaRepository.

Comment: `spring-data-jdbc` is imported through `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`. Ofcourse you shouldn't remove `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as you want to use JPA.